# Application_BeginRequest will execute when network reconnecting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-applications

I have problem in Application_BeginRequest will execute twice when network disconnect and then reconnecting in Global.asax?

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Items["db"] == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Items["pdb"] = NewDb();
            }
        }
```

I have a function and it takes 3 to 5mins to execution if clients network will disconnected between execution what will happen?

```
public JsonResult SaveDetails(int id)
{
  // 100 lines executed 
  // users network will disconnected,
  // 150 lines to be executed. what will happen it executes or not?And Application_BeginRequest will execute again?
}
```

> My problem in database transaction that is my all code is
>   in transaction but sometimes remaining 150 lines only effects in
>   database.

Comment: Do you mean doubt, or that you're worried it _will_? If you mean that you're worried it will, then yes it will. It will be called for each new request to the server.

Comment: @john it is not doubt i have problem.

Comment: @john because i do not what will happen clients network will lost?

Comment: If a connection is lost, a new connection will be established (if the client can do this). It won't continue the same connection.

Comment: @john you mean Application_BeginRequest  will execute again?

Comment: Why would you expect anything to the contrary? How would the server differentiate between a brand new connection, and a re-establishing of the old connection?

Comment: @john Because remaining 150 lines only effected in database and i get new database connection only Application_BeginRequest() Function otherwise i get db in existing HttpContext.Current.Items["pdb"].

Comment: http is a stateless protocol. So as stated by @john your server can't differentiate between an new request and old request coming back after network issues. What you can do is to maintain state yourself with help of caching or other similar strategies

Comment: @It'satrap what is solution for this problem?

Comment: Is this accessible by anonymous users also?

Comment: @It'satrap No it is accessible by authorized user.

Comment: This greatly simplifies your work. Everytime the method is called, add an entry to the cache and remove it when the method completes. In the method, check if the entry is present in the cache. If it is present, then you know that this is an old connection for which method call was not completed

Comment: @It'satrap i already tried this method but the problem is in second half of code is executed without database transaction so 150 lines  effected in database.